# Categories where morphisms are pairs of adjoint functors

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

Is there a particular name for those categories (of categories) where morphisms "come as adjoint pairs", as in the case of toposes and model categories?
Is there any attempt to study them as general structures?

Comment: As far as toposes go, one could take the morphisms as (oppossites of) lex cocontinuous functors and you get the right adjoint for free from the AFT, so don't need them as part of the data. I don't know if there is a general existence result like this for model categories. For _combinatorial_ model categories there probably is one.

Answer (score 1):

In MacLane's CWM (2nd edition) is short section 'IV.8 Composition of adjoints', p.103. There he introduces the 2-category of categories with adjunctions as morphisms. This is called 'Adj' there.

But nothing special is said about this category or some of its subcategories. I think they just embed in the theory of 2-categories. For example 2-categorical aspects of topoi are illuminated in [Johnstone - Sketches of an Elephant vol.1, Part B.3.].

Although it may be worth to take a look at

[Palmquist, Paul H. The double category of adjoint squares. In: Reports of the Midwest Category Seminar V. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1971. S. 123-153.]

Comment: I started precisely having in mind CWM.IV.8; my intention was to know if it is possible to grasp a ("naively doctrinal", let's say) common feature which explains *why* 1-cells in toposes and model categories arise in that way.

Comment: Btw, thanks for pointing me to Palmquist's paper.